# how to replace every directory on my server with index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, server, routes, hosting

I'm trying to ensure that every directory on my server redirects users to index.php instead of letting users view my directory as below screenshot

[image]

I tried to use .htaccess to do this instead of having to create index.php on every directory but it didn't work, below is what .htaccess looks like:

```
ErrorDocument 404 "<H1>Page Not Found!</H1>"

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php73” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php73 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
#Alternate default index page
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Can anyone help with how to solve this?

Comment: `DirectoryIndex index.php` looks for an index.php in the current directory. You can use `DirectoryIndex /index.php` to always make it use the index.php in your root folder. Or you can combine both - `DirectoryIndex index.php /index.php` would serve the index.php from the current directory, if that exists - and fall back to that from the root folder, if not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to solve this by just add `Options -Indexes` on the top of `.htaccess` below is my update code :

```
Options -Indexes

ErrorDocument 404 https://websitelink.com/404.php
ErrorDocument 403 https://websitelink.com

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php73” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php73 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
#Alternate default index page
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Comment: That might have solved your problem, but it isn't exactly what you initially asked for (unless you have configured your ErrorDocument for a 403 status code to be the index.php as well.)

Comment: Yes I just updated the answer to include 403 status

Comment: Specifying an absolute URL for ErrorDocument is kinda wrong as well though - that will cause an external redirect, and the browser will then see a 200 status code for the error document. Should rather be using a relative URL, for the 401 document that is even a requirement.